# Displaying selected option

Tags: jquery, alert, html-select, onchange

Attempting to get my page to display text, directly below the select box, based on what is selected in drop down. So far I have:

```
Choose one:</br>
<select name="book" id="book">
<option value="empty" selected disabled></option>
<option value="Book1">Book1</option>
<option value="Book2">Book2</option>
<option value="Book3">Book3</option>
<option value="Book4">Book4</option>
</select></br></br>
```

with script:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$('#book').change(function() {
  alert('You chose ' + $(this).text() + '.');
});
</script>
```

Problem is that obviously it creates an alert window which is not what I want, and also it displays the whole list and not just the selected item. What would I use in place of alert to display it directly beneath the select box? and why does it display the whole list instead of just the selected option? Thanks in advance for the knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On change, the selects value will be the selected option, so just insert the value after the select, preferable inside an element :

```
$('#book').on('change', function() {
    $('#result_element').text( this.value );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5XAp/2/)

Comment: Won't this add more and more divs as the selection keeps changing?

Comment: @nnnnnn - It sure will !

Comment: OK. Well I'm going to call that a feature and give you +1.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I removed that "feature", and added a fiddle.

Comment: But that was my favourite feature! I guess I'll let you keep the upvote anyway. And for the OP, your `$(this).text()` was getting the whole list because that's what `.text()` is supposed to do: it gets the text contents of the element(s) you call it on and you called it on the select element. You can use `$(this).val()` to get the selected value, or, better, `this.value` as shown in this answer.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response and assistance. I got it to work with your help. Thanks also @nnnnnn for the explanation of .text().